# parsing coordinates from a single kml file with a whole lot of polygons in it

Tags: python-2.7, kml, pykml

i have this kml, file a very long one, and i've managed to obtain the coordinates from a single polygon. but my loop doesn't seem to transfer to the next polygon. is there a way to "point" to the next polygon so i could obtain the coordinates from it? thanks

P.S. i've taken a part of this code from a code from some question here in stackoverflow

```
from pykml import parser
import os, zipfile, os.path
from zipfile import ZipFile as zip

mapCoords = [[]]

def extractAll(zipName):
    z = zip(zipName)
    for f in z.namelist():
        if f.endswith('/'):
             os.makedirs(f)
        else:
             z.extract(f)
    return f

doc = parser.parse(extractAll("temp_kmz")).getroot()

for Polygon in doc.Document.Folder.Placemark.MultiGeometry:
    a = 0
    mapCoords[a].append(doc.Document.Folder.Placemark.MultiGeometry.Polygon.outerBoundaryIs.LinearRing.coordinates)
    a+=1

print mapCoords
```

and here is a cut from the kml file

```
<MultiGeometry>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates> 121.077285,14.626314 121.077006,14.626312 121.077009,14.626040 121.077287,14.626043 121.077285,14.626314</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates> 121.077285,14.626314 121.077563,14.626316 121.077561,14.626587 121.077282,14.626585 121.077285,14.626314</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates> 121.079236,14.626059 121.079234,14.626330 121.079512,14.626332 121.079510,14.626603 121.079231,14.626601 121.078953,14.626599 121.078955,14.626328 121.078958,14.626057 121.079236,14.626059</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates> 121.077561,14.626587 121.077839,14.626590 121.077837,14.626861 121.077834,14.627132 121.077556,14.627129 121.077558,14.626858 121.077561,14.626587</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates> 121.125000,14.627245 121.125000,14.627516 121.124887,14.627515 121.124890,14.627244 121.125000,14.627245</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
```

Comment: does anyone have an answer to my question? :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about how you are calling the attributes about MultiGeometry, yo have to call as follows :

```
for Poly in doc.Document.Folder.Placemark.MultiGeometry.Polygon:

      mapCoords[a].append(Poly.outerBoundaryIs.LinearRing.coordinates)
```

with "Polygon"